# BitDefender says Code Insiders download has Heur.BZC.NZF.Pantera.7.37C58EF0

Tags: visual-studio-code, malware, virus, false-positive

I tried to download the latest Code Insiders at work (the regular Code download scanned fine) and BitDefender said:

> On-Access has detected a threat.Bitdefender has detected malicious behavior on file C:\Users##############\Downloads\VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.40.0-insider.exe and identified it as Heur.BZC.NZF.Pantera.7.37C58EF0. No action taken. The file is to be handled further on by msedge.exe (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge Dev\Application\msedge.exe).

Malware false positive detected

[image]

Comment: Yes, virus scanner heuristics tend to be awful, regardless of product. But what's your question? Sounds like an issue you'd take up with the BitDefender team -- or at worst Microsoft if you really believed there was a virus in there.

Comment: Well, I'll have to submit something to the BitDefender support portal, too, perhaps that we use in a corporate environment but the BitDefender website makes that very difficult to do (because the installer is larger than the max acceptable sample size of 25mb). But the key point is, whatever Microsoft did to the Insiders installer is different than what is in the stable version and it's tripping the BitDefender antivirus as a (likely) false positive. I thought they should know.